# Schengen permit last day to UK

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I am a student with a Singapore passport currently studying in the Czech Republic for a semester. My permit is valid until 2nd of February, I plan to fly to the UK on 2nd feb(last day of visa validity) to travel for 3 days before heading back to Singapore from there.

Would there be any problems, such as exit immigration from the Czech Republic to the UK? I searched online that the UK is not part of Schengen Area Agreement states, and my passport has a visa free entry to the UK.

Comment: Please do not ask again. If you think your question needs more views, edit it so it comes to the top again. Best to register though, so you can edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine. Since your visa is for the Schengen area it will only matter that you leave the Schengen area until feb 2nd. Then when you arrive in UK if your passport has a visa free policy you'll go through the immigration and get a stamp that allows you to enter as a tourist.

you may check their official website to check it out https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa